# Data Access Layer - Designing Class where should responsibility of creating saving be

Tags: c#, data-access-layer, responsibility

I am designing Data Access Layer with ADO.NET 2.0 and C#, Sql Server 2005. I often fight with my brain over where to place those calls. **Which way of the below i should follow for maintainable robust code.**

#### Method 1

```
Public Class Company
{

public string CompanyId
{get;set;}

public string CompanyAddress
{get;set;}

public bool Create()
{
}

public bool Update()
{
}

public bool Delete()
{
}

}
```

#### Method 2

```
Public Class Company
{

public string CompanyId
{get;set;}

public string CompanyAddress
{get;set;}
}
```

and i would use another class like below to do the core data access. Like below

```
Public Class CompanyRepository
{

public Company CreateCompany(string companyId,string companyDescription)
{
}

public bool UpdateCompany(Company updateCompany)
{
}

public bool DeleteCompany(string companyId)
{
}

public List<Company> FindById(string id)
{
}


}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go with method 2. **It is not the Company class's responsibility to read/write from a data source** ([single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). However, I would even go as far as creating an `ICompanyRepository` interface and then creating a `CompanyRepository` implementation for the interface. This way you can inject the ICompanyRepository into the class that needs to save/retrieve company information. It also allows easier unit testing and the ability to create a different implementation in the future (switching from a database to xml files or whatever).

Comment: yup i do use ICompanyRepository to maintain/extend list of methods that Company can extend into. Just that too much code is sometimes not needed in the questions do they ;)

Comment: @Deeptechtons: True enough ;)

Comment: Actually it nso  code- come to the current echnology, please. It is IRepository<T> and generic and it uses a generic DAL. Anyone writing the code himself fo a standard DAL fails junior programming requirements for any of my teams. I wrote a generic DAL 10 years ago before generics where in .NET - today IQueryable<T> is the seach interface, provided by LYNC and you write a LYNC provider. Anything else is a shame. And you write generic methods for updating and saving.

Comment: @TomTom: Yes I do agree with the generic approach to the repository (why recreate the same code every project?). Never used LYNC (or heard of it until today). Time to learn something new!

Comment: @TomTom: Although I should add that trying to force everything into a one-size-fits-all generic repository is not *always* the approach to take. It can lead to leaky abstractions when you don't require everything exposed by the interface (or when you must prevent certain methods (e.g. when you don't want to allow saving/updating because the data source should only be readonly). Use a generic repository when it makes sense (which is *usually*).

Comment: @JasonDown accepted as answer. Although i didn't get much out of TomTom comments. Does he mean instead writing Interface for each repository i should create something generic?

Comment: @Deeptechtons: That is part of what he was saying. Here is a link links to explain it in more detail: http://forums.asp.net/t/1629771.aspx/1 And here is an argument against it (without making some slight modifications): http://richarddingwall.name/2009/01/19/irepositoryt-one-size-does-not-fit-all/

Comment: Actually I say that if you sit down and do that you have NO sense in being in programming - much like a cook having problems making eggs has no future in a professional kitchen.

Comment: @Deeptechtons: Here is information about LYNC: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Lync

Comment: @Jason Down: Actually - sorry. Your link is either outdated or witte nby an idiot. Next time I see a repository with "GetAll" or "GetById" the person gets fired and i sleap his face for incompetence. LINQ solved this problem for years now.

Comment: @Jason Down: AND - your link to Wikipedia is comical. Really. LINQ != LYNC. LINQ = Language Integrated Query. LYNC = Success to Microsoft Office Communication Server, basically a communication system. Totally unrelated link.

Comment: @TomTom: You're the one who wrote LYNC, not LINQ (in your first comment). I know what LINQ is. I just provided a link to LYNC because I don't know what it is and have never heard of it you brought it up (and confused me and obviously the op). Why don't you stop being a jerk and be useful. Provide a better answer instead of being immature.

Comment: Yeah, but i  did not link wikipedia here ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the principle of [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), you will go with your method 2.

Having different responsibilities in different classes does help with creating testable, maintainable code.

This also produces smaller, more cohesive classes that are easier to write, reason about and check for correctness.

As a note, you can use an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) instead of hand crafting your data access layer.

Comment: thank you for that answer, i don't have much experience in the industry to arrive at a decision that's the reason i put this on SO. Could you explain more on how the method2 will help me other than providing `SOP`

Comment: @Deeptechtons - I have added some more detail.

Comment: we could use a ORM we are investigation NHIBERNATE for next project, but now for current project i got no choice :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would stand for second choice, cause

- first you create your `data holder`
- after crate your `operational unit`

So in this case you separate the data from functions that operate on them, making `UnitTesting` notably easier and destributing the responsibilities between different domains of your code, with, possibly, easy bugs localizations.